# Matching Multiple Patterns using Java Regex

Tags: java, regex

I have a file containing records of the following format:

```
1285957838.880      1 192.168.10.228 TCP_HIT/200 1434 GET http://www.google.com/tools/dlpage/res/c/css/dlpage.css [02/Oct/2010:00:00:38 +0530] je02121 NONE/- text/css
```

Which has 11 fields (`[02/Oct/2010:00:00:38 +0530]` is a single field)

I want to write extract fields say 7, 8, 9. Is it possible to extract these fields using Java regex.

Can regex be used to match multiple patterns for the above?

From the above record, I need to extract the fields

```
f1: http://www.google.com/tools/dlpage/res/c/css/dlpage.css  
f2: 02/Oct/2010:00:00:38 +0530  
f3: je02121
```

Comment: Is there any `delimiter` (e.g. a space) that partitions the fields?

Answer (score 14):

Do it sequentially, not all in one pattern (if you have many lines like this, split the lines first, also extract the compiled Pattern to a constant):

```
String input = "1285957838.880      1 192.168.10.228 TCP_HIT/200 1434 GET http://www.google.com/tools/dlpage/res/c/css/dlpage.css [02/Oct/2010:00:00:38 +0530] je02121 NONE/- text/css";
Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("\\[.*?\\]|\\S+").matcher(input);
int nr = 0;
while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println("Match no. " + ++nr + ": '" + matcher.group() + "'");
}
```

**Output:**

```
Match no. 1: '1285957838.880'
Match no. 2: '1'
Match no. 3: '192.168.10.228'
Match no. 4: 'TCP_HIT/200'
Match no. 5: '1434'
Match no. 6: 'GET'
Match no. 7: 'http://www.google.com/tools/dlpage/res/c/css/dlpage.css'
Match no. 8: '[02/Oct/2010:00:00:38 +0530]'
Match no. 9: 'je02121'
Match no. 10: 'NONE/-'
Match no. 11: 'text/css'
```

**Regex Pattern explained:**

```
\\[    match an opening square brace
.*?    and anything up to a
\\]    closing square brace
|      or
\\S+   any sequence of multiple non-whitespace characters
```

Comment: I believe attacking it with two patterns is the right approach. Recently I had to parse very similar logs. Fortunately, the timestamp in brackets was the first field, so I split the log line at the closing bracket and used white space regex delimiter on the rest.

Comment: @Olaf if you want to split(), you need two patterns, agreed. But in my version you only need 1 pattern, which I personally prefer.

Comment: I just went back to my code and incorporated your suggestion. Now my code can handle all permutations of the Extended Squid format, not only the case when date/time in brackets is the first field. Thanks!

Comment: Worked well, I don't want to include opening and closing braces ([]) in output. How can I do that.

Answer (score 5):

Assuming that the only place where spaces are allowed within a field are between the brackets in the date field, and that there are no empty fields, you could use this:

```
Pattern regex = Pattern.compile(
    "^(?:\\S+\\s+){6}   # first 6 fields\n" +
    "(\\S+)\\s+         # field 7\n" +
    "\\[([^]]+)\\]\\s+  # field 8\n" +
    "(\\S+)             # field 9", 
    Pattern.MULTILINE | Pattern.COMMENTS);
Matcher regexMatcher = regex.matcher(subjectString);
while (regexMatcher.find()) {
    for (int i = 1; i <= regexMatcher.groupCount(); i++) {
        // matched text: regexMatcher.group(i)
        // match start: regexMatcher.start(i)
        // match end: regexMatcher.end(i)
    }
}
```

Comment: Less generic than mine, but answers the question perfectly (+1)

Answer (score 1):

use split with regex "[\t\s]+?" and store results in array say s.

Then s[6], s[7]+s[8] and s[9] will be the expected result

Comment: a) `\s` contains `\t`. Use `\s+` instead of `[\t\s]+` b) field no 8 contains a space, so that won't help

Comment: @http://stackoverflow.com/users/342852/sean-patrick-floyd Thats y I've added s[7] + s[8] to get the entire date.

Answer (score 0):

This option not include opening and closing braces ([]) in output

```
    String input = "1285957838.880      1 192.168.10.228 TCP_HIT/200 1434 GET http://www.google.com/tools/dlpage/res/c/css/dlpage.css [02/Oct/2010:00:00:38 +0530] je02121 NONE/- text/css";
    Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("(\\d+/+\\w+/+\\d.* \\+\\d+)|([^\\[]\\S+[^\\]])").matcher(input);
```